# Keep one value or split even based on association to claim no and cpt code

Tags: python, pandas

I am experiencing a little trouble with an exercise assigned to me earlier. Here is a preview of the issue:

This is what i am using to merge:

```
combined = pd.merge(ReportA,ReportB,how='left',left_on=['Service Date','Claim No','Patient Acct No','CPT Code','Modifier 1',],right_on=['Service Date','Claim No','Patient Acct No','CPT Code','Modifier 1'])
```

[image: Snippet]

Or another desired result would be for the "Billed Charge" that is associted to the same Claim No and CPT Code and maybe Modifier, to be split even. Same thing for Balance. If adding the modifier to this equation complicates things then we can leave it out. If this is not possible at all then what about the original desired result displayed in the image above?

The issue is cause by Report A having multiple payment dates. Thanks in advance and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could add extra columns to both Reports, for example: 'Charge No' where each row in a unique group is getting a seperate number:

```
ReportA['Charge No'] = ReportA.groupby(
    ['Service Date','Claim No','Patient Acct No','CPT Code','Modifier 1']
).cumcount()+1
ReportB['Charge No'] = ReportB.groupby(
    ['Service Date','Claim No','Patient Acct No','CPT Code','Modifier 1']
).cumcount()+1
```

Then you can merge them on your previously used groups + 'Charge No':

```
combined = pd.merge(
    ReportA, 
    ReportB,
    how='left',
    left_on=['Service Date','Claim No','Patient Acct No','CPT Code','Modifier 1', 'Charge No'],
    right_on=['Service Date','Claim No','Patient Acct No','CPT Code','Modifier 1', 'Charge No']
)
```

Comment: I will try this out. Thanks for the suggestion